# Spring data save does not update the PK in the persistence context?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, crud

Everytime I use the method save of a JPA Spring data repository it give me back a new object and the Autogenerated PK are not updated in the saved object.

Do I have to update my local object PK with the returned by save method manually?

Code:

```
private void saveProject(){
        Project savedProject = projectRepository.save(projectModel.getProject());
}
```

**savedProject** is not the same as **projectModel.getProject**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project", schema = "public")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    List<User> users;
    [...]
}
```

And:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "public")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    String name;
}
```

So, the user PK is gerenated in Mysql, and everytime I save the project a new User is created because the user in the app is still PKless...

Comment: Code, please. I haven't see it do this.

Comment: If the DB autoGenerate the PK I have to reload my local objects with savedProject to be able to update next time and not create a new object again.

Comment: This is still not sufficient information to reproduce your problem. Repository `save` methods will return a new object when you're using JPA, and this should have the `@Id` populated (you didn't show `Project`). However, this looks like you have foreign-key relationships going on, and that could complicate things. Show your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you save a `new Project()`, JPA will create a new object in the database.

For updating an entity, you need to first bring that entity in the JPA context by fetching it from the database first like so.

```
Project lastProject = projectRepository.findById(PROJECT_ID); //lastProject is now updatable.
lastProject.setName(...);   //update the entity fields
lastProject = projectRepository.save(lastProject); //project will now have the updated name.
```

Comment: Perfect solution... Just added few lines more to update the local project with the PKs of last project...